# Can not convert System.Linq.IOrderedQuerable to System.Collection.Generic.List error

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert a list collection to queryable. When I tried the following code I am getting the error that I can not convert System.Linq.IOrderedQuerable to System.Collection.Generic.List.

```
var test = query.AsQueryable();
return test.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of the function is a List?

```
return test.OrderByDescending(sortExpression).ToList();
```